# Custom domain gitbook suddenly shows error 404?

Tags: gitbook

Our gitbook suddenly show 404, even it works before
This Collection is published but no spaces match its visibility requirements[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

you need publish space to parent collection
https://docs.gitbook.com/getting-started/publishing/space-publishing